# MySQL store demographics in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a platform with multiple clients and each has a large set of demographics that I need to store. With this in mind, it seems I could do one of two things in MySQL. Either:

Option #1: Have a large table with everyone's demographics. For example:

```
Table: clientDemographics

id  |  clientID  |  firstName ....
1   |     34     |  John ......
2   |     12     |  Fred ......
```

Option #2: Split out each client to having their own table:

```
Table: client34_demographics

id  |   firstName ....
1   |   John ......
```

---

```
Table: client12_demographics

id  |   firstName ....
1   |   Fred ......
```

Are there any advantages to splitting the tables out by client (efficiency, security, scalability) or disadvantages? Which of these would be a better method? Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to have each client has it's own table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is not a good idea (creating a table for each demographic). Instead, I would go with something more "normalized" that contains unique identifiable information in the client table, and then additional meta data (demographics) as a lookup:

```
Table: Clients

ClientId | FirstName | LastName | Email
-------------------------------------------------
1        | John      | Smith    | jsmith@email.com
```

---

```
Table: Demographics

DemographicId | Name 
-------------------------------------------------
1             | Gender
2             | Nationality
3             | Age
```

---

```
Table: Clients_Demographics

CDId | ClientId | DemographicId | Value
-------------------------------------------------
1    | 1        | 1             | Male
2    | 1        | 2             | American
3    | 1        | 3             | 27
```

In this way you can easily sort on demographic types, demographic values, clients, etc and all the while saving space in your database, increasing query performance, and keeping your data scalable. By scalable I mean, need to add another Demographic? Just add another row to the Demographics table and then associate a value in the Clients_Demographics table with a Client. If they value is not set (i.e. no row exists) then you know that value can be seen as empty in your forms until they actually set a value.